# Why is the bullet not created realitive to the player?

Tags: game-maker

I'm using GameMaker to make my game and I'm trying to get the player bullet to fire out of the players gun but for some reason even though I checked 'relative', the bullet is still being created at the top of the room.

Why? How could I have the bullet created relative to the player?

Answer (score 1):

The `relative` label can give different results, depending on where used. When an object is created `relative`ly to another object, it means the `x` and `y` coordinates you are giving as parameters will be summed to the object calling the *Create Instance* function. You can achieve this in different ways.

#### Fix your function

Since you want the bullet being created at player's position, you should call the *Create Instance* from within the player object. If you are calling the function from another object, you will get wrong results.

#### Delegate the function

You can also put the *Create Instance* function anywhere you want, as long as the *Applies to* field is referring the player object:

[image]

To do so, from the *Applies to* field select "Object", then choose your player object from the list, and you're done.

#### Use absolute coordinates

Maybe not the best solution, but it will work as well. Instead of creating the bullet `relative`ly, create it at an absolute position (uncheck the `relative` field) and set such position as the player's: use `oPlayer.x` and `oPlayer.y` as *x* and *y* coordinates (change the `oPlayer` object name according to your project).

That's it. Let me know if something isn't working, I'll try to help you. Also, if you could provide some info such as a screenshot of the functions inside your object, we may take a deeper look to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @liggiorgio,

here is a screenshot to better show you what is going on:
http://imgur.com/a/64wBH

Comment: Try this: delete the *Set variable* block on top of the stack, and put a *Check variable* instead of it. So you'll have: "If can_shoot is equal to true" "Set can_shoot to false, create instance, set Alarm 0 to 15"

Comment: 5 how do i make a check variable?

Comment: Take a look at the [Yoyo Docs](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/000_using%20gamemaker/actions/003_control%20actions.html) and read about changing and testing the value of a variable

Comment: If you're fine with this, you can mark the answer as right, according to the community rules

Comment: @ligiggiorogio never mind its still throwing the same stuff

Comment: anyone please help me fix this issue

Comment: @F.Wolf it is clear to me seeing what is written that the bullet is resetting its x and y coordinates to 0. Check its code as well.